# Image file not uploading into server by Python and Flask REST API

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, postman, flask-restful

I am trying to upload an image file to my server powered by Python & Flask framework with REST API. I am trying to send the image from Postman but seems like its not working. I debugged the code so that if the server is receiving the image or not. **My server is receiving image from the post request from Postman but not saving into my destination folder in my server**.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from base64 import b64decode

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response,redirect, url_for,flash
from flask_restful import Api, Resource,reqparse
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bcrypt

import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename



app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'avatar_img' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['avatar_img']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return jsonify({"status": "uploaded"})
```

Here is the screenshot from Postman:

[image]

Everything works fine, I am not getting any server error. **But image not saving to my destination folder!**

Comment: Can you run this through a debugger and get the value of `os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)` -- I expect there's a path issue here.

Comment: yes, i am getting    uploads/avatar.png  as output, but not seeing any file or image in my directory

Comment: So still in that debugger session, can you get the output of `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))`? -- In other words: wrap it in abspath to get the absolute path and make sure there's not a relative path issue?